# AngularJs http get to PHP script returns the php code

Tags: php, http, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to grab an echo from a php script that spits out JSON.

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

What I have in my angular code is the following: 
'use strict';

```
app.factory('HttpRequestService', function($http) {
  var HttpRequestService = {
    async: function() {

      var promise = $http.get('/test.php').then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    },
    load: function() {
        console.log('helloo');
    }
  };
  return HttpRequestService;
});
```

And then in my service I have :

```
HttpRequestService.async().then(function(data) {
    console.log('data is : ' + data);
});
```

but this literary spits the whole php script and not just the echo data:

```
console :
data is : <?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: If you navigate to the php page in browser what happens?

Comment: What happens when you hit the test.php page with your browser? What's the response that comes back. It looks like your php isn't being compiled. Perhaps you didn't run the php module in your web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the response that comes back when you open `test.php` in your browser.

Your php isn't being compiled. Perhaps you didn't run the php module in your web server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a factory, for naming convention sake, you might want to rename it `HttpRequestFactory`

```
app.factory('HttpRequestService', function($http, $q) {
  var HttpRequestService = {
    async: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/test.php')
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
         })
         .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            deferred.reject("An error occured");
         });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  return HttpRequestService;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I completely overlooked that part. I feel so newbish now lol.